# MongoDB query of filter data based on field present in foreign collection after the lookup is taking time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-lookup

I have 2 collections Customers and Orders. I have to filter the customers who have placed the order in the last 60 days. The aggregation that I have written to get this data is taking a lot much time.

**Customers Collection**

```
_id
id
name
phone
order_id
```

**Orders Collection**

```
_id
id
created_at
```

**Data Sample Size**

```
Customers collection has 1M customers and Orders Collection has 160K Orders.
```

I have created the index on **order_id** and **id** fields in the **customers** collection and **id** and **created_at** fileds in the **orders** collection.

I'm running the below aggregations. which is taking time.

**Aggregation 1:**

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "orders",
      localField: "order_id",
      foreignField: "id",
      pipeline:[
        {
          $project:{
            "id":1,
            "created_at":1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "order"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$order"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "id":1,
      "name":1,
      "phone":1,
      "order":1
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "order.created_at":{
        $gt:"2023-12-10"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Aggregation 2:**

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "orders",
      localField: "order_id",
      foreignField: "id",
      pipeline:[
        {
          $project:{
            "id":1,
            "created_at":1
          }
        },
        {
          $match:{
            created_at: {
               $gt:"2023-12-10"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "order"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$order"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "id":1,
      "name":1,
      "phone":1,
      "order":1
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "order.created_at":{
        $gt:"2023-12-10"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Please guide how we can make this aggregation so that it will returns result in less time.

Comment: Can you post some sample documents and the expected output? Likely you can start the aggregation from the `orders` collection and `$match` first to reduce the intermediate result set. Then, perform the `$lookup` back to `customers` collection to reform your expected output. On the other hand, you may also move the `$match` into the first stage of the sub-pipeline to reduce the `$lookup` result set size.

Comment: @ray I have tried both but no impact on execution time.

Comment: Identify the bottleneck first. Have you checked the [explain](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/explain/)?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the customers with an order in the last 60 days or all orders placed in the last 60 days with the `created_at` and the corresponding customer information?

Comment: @Markus I want to retrieve the customers with an order in the last 60 days

Comment: @ray Yes I checked the explain. Please see this https://prnt.sc/h3GWXU4sTjVW

Comment: @tomasjindal don't use screenshots. Instead, [edit] the question to include the text. Also, what is your findings on the explain result?

Comment: @ray As per my findings last pipeline `$match` is taking time. I also tried to filter with other fields from the orders collection, but all are taking time. 

But when I use any field from the customer collection query is works very fast.

Comment: When filtering by a customer-field, I'd expect the optimizer to run the `$match` before the `$lookup` and by that reducing the number of `$lookup`-queries.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to retrieve the customers that have placed an order in the last 60 days would to extend the `customer` documents with the last date that an order has been placed (e.g. `lastOrderDate`). This way, you can avoid an expensive `$lookup` stage by only querying the `customers` collection. When an order is placed, you not only store the order but also update the `customer` document if the `lastOrderDate` is less than the new value.

This way, you can create an index on the `customers` collection and query only one collection, avoiding the performance hit of a lookup per customer document.

If you look at the numbers and assume an 1:n relationship between `customers` and `orders`, you'd reduce the number of `customer` documents that you need to query from 1M to a maximum of 160k which would be further reduced by supporting the query with an index (`lastOrderDate_1` would be enough, but if you want to cover the query, you can also create `lastOrderDate_1_id_1_name_1_phone_1` so that all projected fields are contained in the index).

---

If you cannot change the schema in the `customers` collection, you should try to reduce the amount of documents that are passed through the pipeline as much as possible. In your samples, you put all 1M customers through the pipeline, querying the `orders` collection for each one of them - though only 160k customers can have an order.

There are many customers that do not have an order yet, but as it stands, you cannot identify them beforehand (I assume `order_id` is set without regard if the customer actually has an order or not).

Therefore, I'd try to turn things around and query `Orders` and look up the customer information from there, e.g.

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      created_at: {
        $gt: "2023-12-10",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      id: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      created_at: { $max: "$created_at" },
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "customers",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "order_id",
      as: "customer",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$customer",
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      id: "$customer.id",
      name: "$customer.name",
      phone: "$customer.phone",
      order: {
        created_at: "$created_at",
      },
    },
  },
]
```

Above pipeline is a sample, so please test and adjust it as needed. It aims to make good use of an index `id_1_create_at_1` on the `orders` collection so that the amount of documents that have to be retrieved is reduced as much as possible. Expensive `$lookup` operations are only conducted once per customer due to the `$group` stage.

As a final note, it would also be possible to store the relevant details of the customer in the `order` documents, again avoiding the lookup alltogether.